# JLCPCB Bom Detection from U

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I am trying to order a PCB from JLCPCB and have the following problem:

When I enter the BOM in the Assembly it does not detect U1, all the other components are detected. What could be the mistake?

Photos are screenshots.

[image: JLCPCB Order]

[image: the BOM.csv]

Comment: Ask JLCPCB? Rename it from U to something else?

Comment: You didn't specify an LCSC part number, it is not going to guess based on the comment field.

Comment: I did that in an other try. Did not work as well.

Comment: Maybe the fact that it is the last entry is causing it to get dropped, perhaps switch the order of the parts and see if that works. If it does maybe add a dummy entry.

Comment: No I switched the entries. DId not change.

Comment: It didn't pick up J1 and J2 either. Which are also missing the last field. That's probably a big clue.

Comment: Seems likely you have to find the right part number and enter it in those fields yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it via changing the Reference like U1 to U2 and then updating all the Gerber files. Seems like the problem was a connection between the PCB Files and the BOM.